# Julia DifferentialEquations - LoadError: MethodError: no method matching oneunit(::Type{Any})

Tags: julia

I'm trying to understand the Julia ModellingToolkit interface and am not having a great deal of success.

Taking the code posted on this [link](https://mtk.sciml.ai/dev/tutorials/acausal_components/), and replacing the capacitor with a second resistor e.g.

```
@named resistor = Resistor(R=R) 
@named r2 = Resistor(R=0.5) 
@named source = ConstantVoltage(V=V) 
@named ground = Ground()
 rc_eqs = [ connect(source.p, resistor.p) 
connect(resistor.n, r2.p) 
connect(r2.n, source.n) 
connect(r2.n, ground.g) ] 
@named _rc_model = ODESystem(rc_eqs, t) 
@named rc_model = compose(_rc_model, [resistor, r2, source, ground])
```

Yields the following error

```
LoadError: MethodError: no method matching oneunit(::Type{Any})
Closest candidates are:oneunit(::Type{Union{Missing, T}}) where T at /auto/users/henney/Documents/Oxford/Julia/julia-1.7.2/share/julia/base/missing.jl:105oneunit(::Type{T}) where T at /auto/users/henney/Documents/Oxford/Julia/julia-1.7.2/share/julia/base/number.jl:358oneunit(::T) where T at /auto/users/henney/Documents/Oxford/Julia/julia-1.7.2/share/julia/base/number.jl:357
```

From the error message, it seems to be that the type of one of the variables is undefined, but I'm unsure as to which particular variable, and why the error does not occur when a capacitor is used (the only real difference being the presence of `Derivative(t)` in the `Capacitor` function.

Answer (score 1):

It errors because ODAEProblem would reduce all the equations away. It's tracked in https://github.com/SciML/DiffEqBase.jl/issues/650

As a workaround, you can do

```
prob = ODEProblem(sys, [], (0, 10.0))
solve(prob, Rodas5())
```

for now.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Do you know if there is some sort of guide to interpreting Julia error messages? I would never have worked this out on my own

Comment: We just need to handle this case.